# C++ illegal member initialization in template class

Tags: c++, templates

i have looked through some similar questions about illegal member initialization in c++ with the same error C2614, but it seems is not the same with my problem. 
I have a template class 'Mat2D':

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <assert.h>
template<class T>
class Mat2D
{
private:
    int _rows;
    int _cols;
    T** _data;

public:
    Mat2D()
        :_rows(0), _cols(0), _data(NULL)
    {

    }

    Mat2D(const Mat2D<T>& rhs)
        :_rows(rhs._rows), _cols(rhs._cols)
    {
        cloneData(rhs._data);
    }

    Mat2D(int rows, int cols)
    {
        _rows = rows < 1 ? 1 : rows;
        _cols = cols < 1 ? 1 : cols;
        allocateData();
    }

    Mat2D(int rows, int cols, const T& initValue)
        :Mat2D(rows, cols) //--> error C2614:  'Mat2D<T>' : illegal member initialization: 'Mat2D<int>' is not a base or member 

    {
        all(initValue);
    }

    ~Mat2D()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < _rows; i++)
            delete _data[i];
        delete _data;
    }
//...
};
```

Comment: Show how you initialize an object.

Comment: Constructor delegation is a C++11 feature, so depending on your compiler version it may need a special flag or not be available at all.

Comment: @Alexander Mat2D<int> a(4, 4, 1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Mat2D(int rows, int cols, const T& initValue)
    :Mat2D(rows, cols)
```

This probably won't work since initialization lists are for variables only. Try with

```
Mat2D(int rows, int cols, const T& initValue)
    :_rows(rows), _cols(cols)
```

or copy the contents of the `Mat2D(int cols, int rows)` constructor in this function.

Comment: i think **Mat2D(int rows, int cols, const T& initValue){Mat2D(rows, cols);}** is okay. thanx so much.

Comment: @Ggicci no, it's not; that just constructs a temporary `Mat2D` and it's destroyed immediately. It's not possible to call one constructor from another one (except if that one constructor is in a baser class) pre-C++11.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Yes, you're right. Just now a problem in relation to the temporary Mat2D occurred to me, then I realized my comment at Alexander was wrong. And your comment points it out.